# C++ Line Feed converted to Carriage Return & Line Feed

Tags: c++, visual-c++, char, carriage-return, linefeed

I'm in the process of writing a file that has to save numeric data as chars to be read by a different, already-developed program. It has been simple enough in execution so far, but I'm having trouble storing the numbers 10, which is the line feed character. When attempting to write a char of values 10 into a file, it is automatically converted in to the two separate characters of 13 and 10, Carriage Return and Line Feed.

For example...

```
std::ofstream outputFile(newFileLoc.bin, std::ofstream::out);
std::string newLineNonsense = { 10, 10, 10, 13, 13, 13 };
outputFile << newLineNonsense;
outputFile.close();
```

(Note: newFileLoc.bin is a full file path in the actual code)

opening up newFileLoc.txt with Notepad++ reveals that what should be `lf lf lf cr cr cr` is instead `crlf crlf crlf cr cr cr`. And to confirm this wasnt Notepad++ making modifications, I checked the file size beforehand. A 6 character text file should be 6 bytes, but newFileLoc.bin was 9 bytes in size even before opening the file.

For some compilation information, I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and C++17 as the language standard, and the unicode character set. Changing to Multi-byte did not help.

I'm aware this system is archaic at best, but I'm working within the bounds of pre-developed software. Is there a way to disable the windows-ification of the line feed character? Is this an fstream issue or a string issue?

Comment: To write  the number `10` to a file via a filestream openend in text mode you would write a `std::string{"10"}` not a `char` with value `10`

Comment: Don't mix text and binary output.  If you want to write 3 bytes with the value of `10` and 3 bytes with the value of `13` into the file then use `write` and pass it an array containing your values or do a sperate `write` call for each byte.

Comment: Ah, Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The char '10' is what I want in the file, not the actual human-readable text "10"

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39255649/4117728

Comment: if you want to write binary, dont write text.

Comment: I see, that all makes sense. I wasn't aware of binary mode, that might help a bit 

Comment: Use `std::ofstream outputFile(yourpath, std::ofstream::out, std::ofstream::binary)`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky `std::ofstream outputFile(yourpath, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::binary)`.  `|`, not `,` for the last parameter

Comment: @NathanOliver a typo, edit time limit exceeded. Thanks

Comment: As much of a fan of `string` as I am, using it in this context will often result in a misreading of your intent as you can see in the first comment. Way I see it to prevent insertion of bugs by folks who misread what you did in the future, you either do something different like use an array or `vector` a binary `write` function or you leave a big comment. I strongly prefer the former because I'm also a believer in code being as self-documenting as possible.